# inserting links to publish

Tags: ee1, entry, import, entrylinks

When I try to insert a link under "Publish" on my website, the square appears for me to fill in the https info,  but the square is empty.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which ee version?  Are you talking about an URL fieldtype? Or the url_title? Or a RTE with a link in the text.

Comment: @peter, Since each ExpressionEngine site is unique and custom developed by the developer, it may be helpful for you to share some screenshots, screen recordings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 1.7.1.
I go to a new entry to edit it. I’ve printed a list of titles of my video works. I highlight a title to a video that I want users to be able to access on Vimeo by tapping that title. I highlight the title, then tap the to the “insert/edit link” icon. An empty box appears. This box usually will allow me to insert an https: link. There is nothing in the box, no printing, nothing.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of EE if you can. V1 hasn't been supported in over 8 years (https://expressionengine.com/support/version-support). There are lots of things that could cause it to break including changes by your web host or even browser updates. 
It would be very tough to troubleshoot your situation without an exact copy of the site and knowing the right environment to test on.
You may want to start by opening Dev Tools in your browser and seeing if there are any console errors, next would be the Network tab and see if you have 404 or 500 error codes there.